# How much of a disadvantage am I in as compared to my competition as a postdoc applicant?

Tags: postdocs

I defended my PhD after 5.5 years from starting. While my degree granting date is 6 years from starting. So technically, I have spent 6 years on my PhD.

I failed to secure a postdoc position before my defense. And after defense, I got tangled in visa issues which delayed the starting of an interim postdoc position in my PhD lab.

In March, with the pandemic starting, my visa got more delayed and I stopped applying for postdoc positions due to global lockdowns.

Finally, my visa arrived in May and I was able to start my postdoc with my PhD advisor in June. Now, instead of interim gig, I am considering this as an extended 1-1.5 years engagement with a goal of publishing as many papers as possible and expanding collaborations and knowledge.

During my PhD, I had published 1 First Author (FA) paper and 1 co-authored (CA) paper. Since defending, I have published 2 FA and submitted 2 FA papers. I am also close to submitting 2 CA work and working on multiple projects. So technically, I have been keeping busy since graduating.

It's true that I did not get any positions before defense. But it is also true that my initial visa issues (intensified by the covid) added to my securing a job problems.

I have started looking for positions again, albeit only locally (in my country of residence), which reduces my search pool and the possibility of securing one. And am waiting for responses to judge whether my position has improved from last year or not.

My question is, considering my total time taken to graduate, my first postdoc with my PhD advisor (albeit different topic), objectively, *how much of a disadvantage am I in as compared to my competition solely based on these factors?*

Comment: When we look for postdoc candidates we focus on expertise and quality of the work. This we judge from papers, codes and the interview. Soft skills like communication from the interview, and character and general confirmation of our independent assessment from recommendation letters (I sometimes ask for recommendations from people not listed by the applicant, especially if an obvious referee is missing, such as current supervisor). Time taken to get a degree or age is not something I personally pay attention to.

Comment: Of course, in the current pandemic, nothing is normal and even knowing when it will be ‘normal’ again is, well, unknowable. Do what you can, keep looking forward, and keep an eye out for opportunities.

Comment: None of the things you mentioned seem particularly relevant.

Comment: @Anonymousphysicist How so? Aren't they important?

Comment: Well, your publications are relevant.  Your question is off-topic.

Comment: What would an answer like "you are 40% worse off" tell you?